# Enable the controls in a InfoPath 2010 read-only view 

Tags: infopath

Hi 
I would like to display a read-only infopath form the the end-users.I have created a read-only view,everything works perfectly apart from the file attachments.In a a read-only infopath form view , users could not download the file attachments.Is there a way I could ovverride this just for the file attachment?Otherwise ,I have to create a rule to manually make every controls read-only on the form.
Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ybbest, I was just researching the same thing.  You'll need custom code in order to open, instead of download, the file attachment

Code here:
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-8-InfoPath_2007_-_Extracting_those_pesky_Binary_attachments.aspx

Referenced Thread:
[[infopath File Attachment - Run/View instead of Download?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/infopath-file-attachment-run-view-instead-of-download)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/infopath-file-attachment-run-view-instead-of-download)

Answer (score 0):

You can only display Infopath **Picture of File Attachment** field as Picture/File Attachment control or Calculated Value (field). Unfortunately Calculated value shows entire base64 contents of the attached file so it does not help much.

Two options IMHO:

1. Remove that field from the read-only view all together
2. On edit view add additional required String field where user filling form would enter filename and display it on read-only view

Please note: InfoPath views are nice but they are just views, this is not a security feature and skillful user can still retrieve your files from InfoPath.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply however I do not get the second option?Let people type in the file name they attach to the form and display the form name in the read-only view?But I would like people to see the attchment content?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem then, if you would like people to be able to open attachments, what do you mean by "users could not download the file attachments". As soon someone opens attachment it has been downloaded to their computer.